# Why wasn't Snape punished for attempting to save Harry's life?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, severus-snape, philosophers-stone

In the first book of Harry Potter, it is revealed that Snape was not trying to curse Harry's broom; he was trying to save him. But we also learn that Professor Quirrell was behind it the whole time, with Voldemort living behind his turban. Voldemort probably knew everything happening around Quirrell, so why didn't he punish Snape for betraying him and helping Harry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Warning: spoilers for Book 6.

This is addressed in Chapter 2 of Half-Blood Prince.

In this scene, Bellatrix is questioning Snape's loyalty to Voldemort. She's basically questioning every decision Snape has made since Voldemort's first defeat. Here's his response to his actions during the first book

> “I  think  you  next  wanted  to  know,”  he  pressed  on,  a  little  more  loudly,  for  Bellatrix  showed  every  sign  of  interrupting,  “why  I  stood  between  the  Dark  Lord  and  the  Sorcerer’s  Stone.  That  is  easily  answered.  He  did  not  know  whether  he  could  trust  me.  He  thought,  like  you,  that  I  had  turned from faithful Death Eater to Dumbledore’s stooge. He was in a pitiable condition, very weak, sharing  the  body  of  a  mediocre  wizard.  He  did  not  dare  reveal  himself  to  a  former  ally  if  that  ally  might  turn  him  over  to  Dumbledore  or  the  Ministry.  I  deeply  regret  that  he  did  not  trust  me.  He  would have returned to power three years sooner. As it was, I saw only greedy and unworthy Quirrell attempting to steal the stone and, I admit, I did all I could to thwart him.”

Snape is claiming (falsely of course) that since Voldemort didn't explicitly reveal himself to Snape, he was unaware of who Quirrell really was, and therefore didn't know he was opposing Voldemort.

Since Voldemort believed Snape's story, there was no punishment needed.

Comment: *Snape is claiming (falsely of course) that since Voldemort didn't explicitly reveal himself to Snape, he was unaware of who Quirrell really was, and therefore didn't know he was opposing Voldemort.* Do you mean by this that Snape really **did** know that Quirrel was hosting Voldemort the whole time?

Comment: I guess it's never out right stated that he did. But to me, it makes sense that Dumbledore and Snape had to know. In one of Snape's memories shown in book 7, Dumbledore says (to Snape)  ‘Keep an eye on Quirrell, won’t you?’. Dumbledore is presented as an extremely intelligent and perceptive wizard. To me, his coy "keep an eye" is the equivalent to anyone else saying "I've figured out that Voldemort is hiding in Quirrell's hat. We should take care of that."